# Import Into Localhost (derby database) via db2Move

Tags: import, db2, export

I use the following to export the information: `db2move server1 export -sn theschema -tn table,  table2, table3`

and it exports fine.

I'm trying to import all the exported information into a derby (local) database.

I've tried using:

```
db2move C:/IBM/WCToolkitEE60/db/mall import
```

The problem is, it says:

```
Application code page not deteermined, using ANSI codepage 1252

Error: String 'C:/IBM/WCToolkitEE60/db/mall

**Error - Line Buffer overrun.
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The DB is DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db2move` is a utility for reading and writing to DB2 databases.  You can't use db2move to write to a Derby database.

Comment: You can export data in ascii delimited format using the EXPORT utility in DB2.  Does derby have a utility to read delimited files and write the data into tables?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up just using SQL